# Typedef structure with undeclared variable

Tags: c, variables

I'm just starting to learn C for a few weeks and have been trying to familiarise with structures but to no avail. I'm currently stuck on this code. I cannot figure out why my program does not pick up the variables. There is a `printf()`function at the end of the program that i have not put in yet due to it being irrelevant.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 11 
typedef struct date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} date_t;
typedef struct student{
    char name[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    float gpa;
    date_t birthday;
} student_t;

int main(void)
{
    student_t student;
    date_t date;
    printf("Enter name>");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("Enter birthday: day>");
    scanf("%d", &day);
    if (day <1 ||day >31){
        printf("Invalid day. Enter birthday: day>");
        scanf("%d", &day);
    }
    printf("Enter birthday: month>");
    scanf("%d", &month);
    if (month< 1 || month >12){
        printf("Invalid month. Enter birthday:>");
        scanf("%d", &month);
    }
    printf("Enter birthday: year>");
    scanf("%d", &year);
    if (year >2017 || year<1900){
        printf("Invalid year. Enter birthday: year>");
        scanf("%d", &year);
    }
    printf("Enter GPA>");
    scanf("%4f", &gpa);
    if (gpa <0 || gpa > 4){
        printf("Invalid GPA. Enter GPA>");
        scanf("%4f", &gpa);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Typedef structure with undeclared variable" - What?? A type is not a variable and vice-versa.

Comment: Apologize if my term is not correct. Basically when i compile the program, the variables such as "name",  gpa, month, etc are not declared and came up as an error

Comment: when you tried to read from the console you need to set the correct parameter, you have 2 parameters which they are structures to refer a field inside a structure you need the instance of the structure (e.g student) followed by . (if the instance is a pointer then ->) and then the required field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure's member variables must be accessed through the structure variables. In your program, you are trying to access members of both structures (`date` or `date_t` & `student` or `student_t`) by the name of their members and not using their structure variables.
eg:

```
student_t student;
date_t date;
printf("Enter name>");
scanf("%s", &name);
```

is wrong.

```
student_t student;
date_t date;
printf("Enter name>");
scanf("%s", student.name);
```

should be used instead.
Also as `name` is a character array (or string) you need use the `&` in `scanf()` as the name of an array itself returns its base address. By giving the address to `scanf()`, you are telling it the address where the read values should be stored.

Similarly,

```
printf("Enter birthday: day>");
scanf("%d", &day);
if (day <1 ||day >31){
    printf("Invalid day. Enter birthday: day>");
    scanf("%d", &day);
}
```

should be

```
printf("Enter birthday: day>");
scanf("%d", &date.day);
if (date.day <1 ||date.day >31){
    printf("Invalid day. Enter birthday: day>");
    scanf("%d", &date.day);
}
```

Here, the `&` operator is required as `date.day` is not an array but an integer variable.

This, I think, is your problem.